# How to mock a function with .then from a hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function from a hook called in my component.

My component:

```
... 
const handleCompleteContent = (contentId: string) => {
  postCompleteContent(contentId, playerId).then(data => {
    if (data === 201) {
...
```

Caller:

```
if (isOpen && contentInfo.type === 0 && !contentInfo.isComplete) {
  handleCompleteContent(contentInfo.id);
}
```

Test:

```
expect(postCompleteContent).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Imported function from worldhooks

```
import { postCompleteContent } from '~/hooks/worldhooks';
```

I mocked the hook:

```
jest.mock('~/hooks/worldhooks');
```

Tried to mock '201' return to the function:

```
const mockPostCompleteContent = jest.fn(() => ({ data: 201 }));

(postCompleteContent as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({
    postCompleteContent: mockPostCompleteContent,
});
```

But, when I run the test:

```
   TypeError: postCompleteContent is not a function                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  50 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  51 |   const handleCompleteContent = (contentId: string) => {                                                                                                                                                                     
> 52 |     postCompleteContent(contentId, playerId).then(data => {
     |     ^
```

`postCompleteContent` function:

```
export async function postCompleteContent(contentId: string, playerId: string) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const content = { contentId, playerId };

  const response = await api.post('Content/CompletedContent', content);
  return response.status;
}
```

`api` is `axios.create`.

What's wrong? Or, how can I do that?

Comment: What exactly is the connection between mockPostCompleteContent and the implementation? Please give a [mre], rather than disconnected snippets.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there's no connection! Just created 'mockPostCompleteContent' to try set 'return data: 201' to postCompleteContent mocked function. I already updated it with tmarwen answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can profile mock the `~/hooks/worldhooks` module with custom definition:

```
import { postCompleteContent } from '~/hooks/worldhooks';
// other imports

jest.mock('~/hooks/worldhooks', () => {
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        postCompleteContent: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: 201 })
    };
});
```

Comment: tried and still 'TypeError: postCompleteContent is not a function'

Comment: I edited my question with the postCompleteContent function

Comment: Would please update you post with the caller part, meaning the code block under test using the `postCompleteContent` if the call is direct.

Comment: done! I updated with caller and test

Comment: Are you able to inspect the value of `postCompleteContent`? I hardly can see what is missing with the provided solution unless an overloading function is trailing in your test.

Comment: I dont think so... the component works like a charm, but can't test because say it's not a fucntion...